# Foreign Key Constraint Failed 787 causing abort on attempt to insert entry into table

Tags: android, sqlite

Trying to insert into my `Accounts` table. The data is collected fine and the thing runs smooth up until after it confirms that the account is added. At which point the operation is aborted due to a Foreign Key Constraint Failure shown here :

**LogCat**

```
04-01 22:58:58.750  23053-23053/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (787) abort at 37 in [INSERT INTO Accounts(Terms,Amount,AccountName,DateCreated,Status,Balance,Purpose,PayPeriod) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
04-01 22:58:58.999  23053-23053/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting Terms=0 Amount=10000 AccountName=Acc 1 DateCreated=04-01-2015 22:58:58 Status=1 Balance=10000 Purpose=test PayPeriod=1
```

I've pulled my dbfile and opened it to check if the tables `Accounts` referenced we're populating properly and they are. I've also ran my database schema in  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fb9fd/1) to see where it fails and ran without problems.

Now I'm lost and don't know what I should be looking for, if anyone can point me in the direction of my mistake it would be greatly appreciated.

**Database Helper**

`onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + termsTable + " (" + colTermsID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colTermsClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + periodTable + " (" + colPeriodID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colPeriodClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + statTable + " (" + colStatusID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colStatClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + accountsTable + " (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colName + " TEXT, " +
            colAmount + " Integer, " +
            colPurpose + " TEXT, " +
            colTerms + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPeriod +" INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colBalance +" INTEGER, "+
            colStatus + " INTEGER DEFAULT '1'," +
            colDate + " TEXT, " +
            colEditDate + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colTerms + ") REFERENCES " + termsTable + " (" + colTermsID + ") " + "," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colPeriod + ") REFERENCES " + periodTable + " (" + colPeriodID + ") " + "," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colStatus + ") REFERENCES " + statTable + " (" + colStatusID + "));");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + payTable + " (" + colPayID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
            colGroupID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPayBal + " TEXT, " +
            colInterest + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDue + " TEXT, " +
            colDateDue + " TEXT, " +
            colPaid + " Integer, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colGroupID + ") REFERENCES " + accountsTable + " (" + colID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewAccs +
            " AS SELECT " + accountsTable + "." + colID + " AS _id," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colName + "," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colAmount + "," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colPurpose + "," +
            " " + termsTable + "." + colTermsClass + "," +
            " " + periodTable + "." + colPeriodClass + "," +
            " " + accountsTable+ "." + colBalance + "," +
            " " + statTable + "." + colStatClass + "," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colDate + "," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colEditDate + "" +
            " FROM " + accountsTable +
            " JOIN " + termsTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colTerms + " = " + termsTable + "." + colTermsID +
            " JOIN " + periodTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colPeriod + " = " + periodTable + "." + colPeriodID +
            " JOIN " + statTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colStatus + " = " + statTable + "." + colStatusID );

    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewPmnts +
            " AS SELECT " + payTable + "." + colPayID + " AS _id," +
            " " + accountsTable + "." + colID + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colPayBal + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colInterest + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colPayDue + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colDateDue + "," +
            " " + payTable + "." + colPaid + "" +
            " FROM " + payTable +
            " JOIN " + accountsTable + " ON " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + " = " + accountsTable + "." + colID );

    InsertTerms(db);
    InsertPeriods(db);
    InsertStatus(db);

}
```

`AddAccount` ( method within DatabaseHelper )

```
void AddAccount(Account acc) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colName, acc.getName());
    cv.put(colAmount, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colPurpose, acc.getPurpose());
    cv.put(colTerms, acc.getTerms());
    cv.put(colPeriod, acc.getPeriod());
    cv.put(colBalance, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colDate, acc.getDate());
    cv.put(colStatus, acc.getStatus());

    db.insert(accountsTable, colName, cv);
    db.close();


}
```

Comment: Based on the values you are trying to insert, there must be a termsTable row with id 0, a statTable row with id 1, and a periodTable row with id 1.  If any one of those rows does not exist you will get a foreign key constraint error.  My guess is you don't have a terms row with id 0.

Comment: Scratch that, uninstalled the app and tried again fresh and it went through without a hitch. Still curious as to why terms needed row 0 while the other needed row 1. Either way I just populated them all from row 0, thanks for the help just post it as an answer anytime so I can accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the values you are trying to insert, there must be a termsTable row with id 0, a statTable row with id 1, and a periodTable row with id 1. If any one of those rows does not exist you will get a foreign key constraint error. My guess is you don't have a terms row with id 0.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.